# Detect undefined symbols in C header file

Tags: c, compiler-construction, libraries

Suposse I coded a C library which provides a bunch of "public" functions, declared in a `mylib.h` header file. Those functions are supposedly implemented in (say) a `mylib.c` file which is compiled to a (say) static lib `mylib.c -> mylib.o -> mylib.a`.

Is there some way to detect that I forgot to provide the implementation of some declared function in `mylib.h`? (Yes, I know about unit testing, good practices, etc - and, yes, I understand the meaning of a plain function declaration in C).

Suppose `mylib.h` declares a `void func1();` and this function was not coded in the provided library. This will trigger an error only  if the linker needs to use that function. Otherwise, it will compile ok and even without warnings - AFAIK. Is there a way (perhaps compiler dependent) to trigger a warning for declared but not implemented functions, or there is any other way to deal with this issue?

BTW: [nm -u](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?nm) lists not all undefined declared functions, but only those "used" by the library, i.e., those functions that will trigger an error in the linking phase if not declared somewhere. (Which makes sense, the library object file does not know about header files, of course.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, the most reliable way is to have a program (or possibly a series of programs) which formally exercise each and every one of the functions.  If one of the programs fails to link because of a missing symbol, you've goofed.

I suppose you could try to do something by editing a copy of the header into a source file (as in, file ending `.c`), converting the function declarations into dummy function definitions:

Original:

```
extern int somefunc(void);
```

Revised:

```
extern int somefunc(void){}
```

Then compile the modified source with minimum warnings - and ignore anything to do with "function that is supposed to return a value doesn't".  Then compare the defined symbols in the object file from the revised source with the defined symbols in the library (using `nm -g` on Unix-like systems).  Anything present in the object file that isn't present in the library is missing and should be supplied.

Note: if your header includes other headers of your own which define functions, you need to process all of those.  If your header includes standard headers such as `<stdio.h>`, then clearly you won't be defining functions such as `fopen()` or `printf()` in the ordinary course of events.  So, choose the headers you reprocess into source code carefully.

Answer (score 2):

There's no easy way.

For example, you can analyse the output of `clang  -Xclang -ast-print-xml` or `gcc-xml` and filter out declarations with no implementations for a given .h file.

Answer (score 0):

You could grep for signatures of exported function in both .h and .c, and compare the lists.
Use wc -l for counting matches, Both numbers should be equal.

Another thought, just came to my mind. It is ihmo not possible to handle it using compiler. it is not always the case, that function declares in mylib.h is implemented in mylib.c

Comment: what is mylib.h doing declaring functions it does not provide?  A header is a contract with the outside world.  It defines what is necessary for the user of the library to know, and declares the functions it provides.  (If you're referring to nested headers, then you're right; if mylib.h needs stdio.h, then (obviously) libmine.a will not provide an implementation of fopen().  But it should declare all the functions it does define, and they should be declared in one header, or in a few related headers that are automatically included by mylib.h.)

Comment: @ Jonathan: The world is not always that ideal (at least as my experience shows). The code could be e.g. auto-generated - each chunk (e.g. FSM) in a separate .c file, or the implementation could be done in another language (e.g. ASM), or the implementation names could be composed at compile-time using pre-processor, etc. ...

Answer (score 0):

> Is there some way to detect that I forgot to provide the implementation of some declared function in mylib.h?

Write the implementation first, then worry about header contents -- because that way, it can be flagged.

Comment: Generally, it is best to write the function into the header just before you implement the function in the source.  Your compilation rules shouldn't allow you to define an externally visible function without a prototype already existing.  That discipline takes you a long way - and really isn't hard.